# When are we part of something and when is something a part of us?

Tags: consciousness

"I wanted to be a part of something bigger"

"Hello people of the Internet" (implying the Internet has ownership of people)"

Comment: Some philosophies go very deep into this type of questions. So please explain the words 'I' and 'We'. [The physical body, the densest aspect of the human personality, contains the five organs of perception and the five organs of action. The size and shape of the body differ from individual to individual, but the essential material composing it and the functions of the organs are common to all. Again, the subtlest aspect, the Consciousness, which is the core of man's composite personality, is one and same in all human beings. The variable factor in man is the mind and intellect equipment.]

Comment: The most simple distinction is found in _constitutive relationships_. If a body is made up of cells for example, cells play a constitutive role in the constitution of an organ and an organism. But one wouldn't say that the organism is a part of the cell. I'd also be careful with the use of the word "ownership" as it's a more restrictive designation of the internet's relationship with people than being an element of a set would imply.

Comment: Check out John Searle's "[Collective Intentionality](http://ist-socrates.berkeley.edu/~jsearle/130/COLLINTWRD.doc)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mereology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mereology/) is the philosophical field of study of parts and their relation to wholes. The field itself is usually split between two different topics of conversation. One of these topics is the field of mathematical logic. In mathematical logic, mereology usually refers to the idea of a subset.

> [Whereas set theory is founded on the membership relation between a set and its elements, mereology emphasizes the meronomic relation between entities, which—from a set-theoretic perspective—is closer to the concept of inclusion between sets.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mereology)

The second topic is the study of metaphysical parts and wholes. This is most certainly the topic that relates the most to your question and it also uses the concept of a subset. Parthood is defined to be a sense of [partial ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) of the set and subsets, meaning that there is some sort of order as to what parts come before or after others. The partial ordering is defined to have three properties:

> 1. [Everything is part of itself. (Reflexivity)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mereology/#ParParOrd)
> 2. [Any part of any part of a thing is itself part of that thing. (Transitivity)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mereology/#ParParOrd)
> 3. [Two distinct things cannot be part of each other. (Antisymmetry)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mereology/#ParParOrd)

Given this definition, we can say that something is a part of us when it obeys those three axioms in relation to ourselves. We are definitely part of ourselves (reflexivity). Our cardiovascular system is a part of us, and therefore so are all parts of our cardiovascular system, such as the heart (transitivity). Finally, we are not part of each other, you are not a part of me and I am not a part of you (antisymmetry). Now, in regards to the language of the last example, we may be part of each other's lives. If you read this answer to your question I will be taking part in your life, at least for a moment. However, in regards to our biological structure, I am not a part of your body and you are not a part of mine. We are dissimilar in terms of the specific atoms and molecules that make up our bodies and therefore we are not parts of each other.

Similarly, we can say that we are part of a whole when we respect those three axioms in regards to it. Society is a whole that we are a part of. Society is a part of itself (reflexivity). We are a part of families, we are a part of society, and the families themselves are a part of society (transitivity). Things that are completely dissimilar to society are not part of society (antisymmetry). We have things in common with society, such as families or communities or ourselves, therefore we are not completely distinct from society.

Another central idea to the study of parts is the concept of supervenience.

> [A set of properties A supervenes upon another set B just in case no two things can differ with respect to A-properties without also differing with respect to their B-properties. In slogan form, “there cannot be an A-difference without a B-difference”.](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/supervenience/)

Supervenience relates two things together in a way such that one of them is dependent on the other. A common example is

> [Psychology supervenes on biology. Biology supervenes on chemistry. Chemistry supervenes on physics.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branches_of_science)

Let's start from the bottom and use the example of changes to a property. Chemistry is said to supervene on physics because any change to physics will alter chemistry. By "a change to physics" we mean some rule such as "quarks no longer stick together by gluons to form protons." If this were to happen protons could no longer form. Chemistry is the study of the interaction between atoms and atoms are made of protons and electrons (and neutrons). If protons could not exist atoms would not form and the laws of chemistry would change. Similarly, think of how that would effect the other fields up the chain. If chemical reactions ceased to happen, biology would not exist either. If there were no biological organisms we would not have the means for psychology to exist.

One puzzling thing that mereology considers is the problem with [vagueness](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/vagueness/). It is well documented that natural language runs into conceptual problems with vagueness. Consider the paradox of the heap:

> [Consider a heap of grain on the ground. If we were to remove one piece of grain from the heap it would not cease to be a heap. However, if we remove all but one of the grains it seems that it would make sense to no longer call it a heap. What happens if we remove one grain at a time until there is one left. When is it appropriate to say the heap ceases to become a heap?](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/sorites-paradox/)

How should we go about solving this? The problem with vagueness has to do with vague, or [fuzzy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-fuzzy/), predicates. Heap itself is not well defined. We do not have any sort of specific measurable to apply to a heap, such as a minimum size or number of composite objects. Without such a definition we will not be able to perfectly assign the predicate of heap to certain objects. Some proposed solutions to this paradox, in respect to fuzzy logic, regard defining a predicate such as "close to a heap" or "almost a heap." These predicates give more room to allow for a satisfactory to what constitutes a heap and what does not.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is not clearly specified, the answer may divert.

Do you agree that you have 3 states -- waking state, dreaming state & deep sleep state?  If yes,

When you are in **waking state** normally you will feel that you are a part of something bigger (including Internet).

When you are in **dreaming state** everything that you feel as a part of the  dream is a part of you. [If you are asking about you (singular) only]

In both these cases the subject is you.

Actually the 'feeling' -- 'we' is a creation of the mind.

When you use this term you will have to consider a mother and the child in the womb and think about whether there exists  anything as their part.

Until Truth Realization we consider ourselves as 'Jivatmas'. Read about [Virat Purusha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10211/who-is-virat-purusha)

Answer (score 0):

Theres the notion of [dependent origination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prat%C4%ABtyasamutp%C4%81da) or *pratityasamutapada*; "if this exists, then that exists; if this ceases to exist, then that ceases to exist".

This is a very broad characterisation, and appears almost empty; as ideas that approach the condition of truth that are universally valid often are: they are emptied of all particulars.

The important thing here is to contrast it with another general truth: if something is, it is; and if it isn't, it isn't; they have self-being, standing on their own ground; they have essences; this also has a very long tradtion, for example Plato alludes to it in the *[Timeaus](http://www.yorku.ca/pclassic/Plato/Timaeus/timaeus1.htm)*:

> What is that which always is and has no becoming; and what is that which is always becoming and never is?

to which he answers:

> That which is apprehended by intelligence and reason is always in the same state; but that which is conceived by opinion with the help of sensation and without reason, is always in a process of becoming and perishing and never really is.

This of course is Parmenides formula; here there can be no *real* becoming or passing away, as the things that are have self-essences; and therefore permanent; in a modern guise, they are atoms.

However, dependent origination is relational; the things that are, are relations; hence they lack *svabhava*, intrinsic essences or self being (*sva*=self, *bhava*=being); they are because of the 'network' of relations; they *can* come to be and they *can* pass away, essentially because they lack *svabhava*.

From [Nagarjunas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagarjuna) *Madyama-karika* (verses of the centre - *madhya* (centre), verses (*karika*))

> Whatever arises dependently
>
> Is explained as empty.
>
> Thus dependent attribution
>
> Is the middle way.
>
> Since there is nothing whatever
>
> That is not dependently existent,
>
> For that reason there is nothing
>
> Whatsoever that is not empty

Here empty should be understood as lacking *svabhava*; ie everything is relational.

To your headline question, everything is then both a part and a whole; as to the statement in the body of your text, the people of the internet do not constitute a 'people' as traditionally understood...I mean in the traditional categories of Western political discourse.